# Does Html.Raw increase the size of the page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I am working on an MVC project. I have to add elements dynamically with data through Ajax call. I have to use server side variable (Dictionary) in the JavaScript. So in Ajax success callback, i am using the server side variable like this,

```
translatedDictionary = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TranslationDictionary));
```

TranslationDictionary is my server side dictionary type variable and translatedDictionary  is my JavaScript variable. My question is whether doing this will increase the page size when page first renders, i mean will using "Html.Raw" going to have any impact on the page load time.

Comment: it inserts the value directly into the page as html so it will increase load time by the number of extra characters it has to load - if you are using it in an ajax success callback - surely you should just be using js and have no need for html raw

Comment: but i am inserting the values on Ajax success callback, will it still impact the page size before Ajax call ?

Comment: Html.Raw is called when the page renders so whatever you are doing will be output when the page is rendered - if you are trying to use a var from the success callback, then you need to use js and work with your ajax response - it would be good to show your whole ajax request so we can see the code in context

Comment: I am not getting it from Ajax response. Its just a server side variable that i get when the page is rendered. I need some values from this server side variable when on Ajax success, that's why i am using it in Ajax success callback.

Comment: Then you are rendering the output in your page when it is loaded (it doesn't matter that it is inside your success call - it is still rendered on page load) so I refer you back to my initial comment

Comment: my point is, that line will only be executed on Ajax success, so how is it working even without getting called.

Comment: yes but rendered on page load - the data has to load to be used and you load it when the page is rendered - what's the point of asking a question if you do not listen to what is being said

Comment: I am just asking, saw your edited comment after commenting. By the way Thanks :)

Comment: Put it this way - if you write a load of js and put it in an external file that is included in your page - that file still has to load, even if the js is not used a straight away - same for your ajax function - it loads straight away even though you do not use it until you make your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

The only time you will be going to wait for is the interval that the server-side machine will need to process this function call `Json.Encode(TranslationDictionary)`.Then, on task finished, it returns an HTML page to the client, which will be rendered to the user.

So those **intervals can depend from task to task**.

In your case, since you are using an ajax to request that page, the ajax will be waiting for the callback as much as the server needs to process `Json.Encode(TranslationDictionary)` among processing other technical stuff.